# Do you know a fairly up-to-date ArcExplorer tutorial video for non-gis staff?

Tags: training

Does anyone know of a fairly up-to-date ArcExplorer tutorial video to show to our non GIS staff who will be using ArcExplorer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ESRI Virtual Campus.There are lot of courses about ESRI products.This is the URL

http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

i havent look youtube (everytime there is a new and good video tutorial on youtube or vimeo) but you can watch What's New in ArcGIS Explorer and Getting Started: The Ribbon, Navigation, and More in [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/demos.html) and you can reach Flyers and Podcasts in [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/flyers-podcasts.html).

i hope it helps you...

Comment: We can't access YouTube.

Comment: I saw those but the first one doesn't work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: why dont you reach youtube? what is your country or work ?

Comment: Youtube is blocked by my company.  No one would be able to view the training.  Maybe I can do some screen capture from home and serve out that way.  Not ideal though.

Comment: There are free youtube downloaders available which you could use at home then bring to work.  Or ask your IT department to grant access for training purposes.